# Install mechanize with Ruby 2.3 on Windows 7 got error

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm trying to install Mechanize with Ruby 2.3 on Windows 7. However I got the following error. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

```
PS C:\DevKit> ruby --version
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]
PS C:\DevKit> gem install mechanize
Fetching: net-http-digest_auth-1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed net-http-digest_auth-1.4
Fetching: net-http-persistent-2.9.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed net-http-persistent-2.9.4
Fetching: mime-types-2.99.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mime-types-2.99.1
Fetching: unf_ext-0.0.7.2-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.7.2-x64-mingw32
Fetching: unf-0.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed unf-0.1.4
Fetching: domain_name-0.5.20160310.gem (100%)
Successfully installed domain_name-0.5.20160310
Fetching: http-cookie-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed http-cookie-1.0.2
Fetching: mini_portile2-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.0.0
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.7.2-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2.
PS C:\DevKit> gem install nokogiri --pre
Fetching: mini_portile2-2.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.1.0
Fetching: pkg-config-1.1.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pkg-config-1.1.7
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
Nokogiri is built with the packaged libraries: libxml2-2.9.3, libxslt-1.1.28, zlib-1.2.8, libiconv-1.14.
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x64-mingw32
Parsing documentation for mini_portile2-2.1.0
Installing ri documentation for mini_portile2-2.1.0
Parsing documentation for pkg-config-1.1.7
Installing ri documentation for pkg-config-1.1.7
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x64-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x64-mingw32
Done installing documentation for mini_portile2, pkg-config, nokogiri after 3 seconds
3 gems installed
PS C:\DevKit> gem install mechanize
ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2.
PS C:\DevKit>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly telling that`nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2`.
The Ruby version must be in between **1.9.2 and 2.3**

May be **ruby version 2.2** should work for you

**Edit:** You can try

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
```

and then run `bundle install`

Comment: Yeah, it seems true. I want to know if there is any workaround to use Ruby 2.3?

Comment: Check my edited answer!! Let me know if this Works!!

Comment: This happens only on Windows!! You may also try `gem install nokogiri --pre`