# Unable to gem install nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When attempting to use `gem install nokogiri`

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2.
```

However if I do `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [i386-mingw32]
```

I've attempted to install it locally, `gem install --local nokogiri` and it runs through the install process, however when I attempt to use the gem, it won't find the file:

```
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
: cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
```

Does anyone have a work around for this? Or am I pretty much stuck without `nokogiri`?

Comment: gem might be running a different version of ruby, and installing it in a different place than ruby. type `which gem` and `which ruby` (assuming you're using mingw on windows)

Comment: @Aaron_H gem: `/c/Ruby23/bin/gem`
ruby: `/c/Ruby23/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer was staring us in the face, your version of nokogiri requires Ruby *less than* 2.3, and you're running ruby 2.3.

It seems you're not the only one with this issue: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1456

Comment: I just got it installed, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some hassle and some research, I used `gem install nokogiri --pre` and wouldn't you know it:

```
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Nokogiri is built with the packaged libraries: libxml2-2.9.3, libxslt-1.1.28, zlib-1.2
.8, libiconv-1.14.
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x86-mingw32
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 12 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I found the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640428/install-mechanize-with-ruby-2-3-on-windows-7-got-error) I've also looked into it on GitHub (as mentioned by Aaron_H) and it seems that this is only happening on Windows, so if you really need `nokogiri` you need to do `gem install nokogiri --pre` in order to get it (on Windows 7 anyways).