# Unable to gem install mechanize

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234362/unable-to-gem-install-nokogiri)

While doing `gem install mechanize` I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2.
```

However, before you chalk this up as me being an idiot and not knowing what I'm doing, if I run `nokogiri -v`, I get this:

```
# Nokogiri (1.6.8.rc3)
    ---
    warnings: []
    nokogiri: 1.6.8.rc3
    ruby:
      version: 2.3.0
      platform: i386-mingw32
      description: ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [i386-mingw32]
      engine: ruby
    libxml:
      binding: extension
      source: packaged
      libxml2_path: "/home/flavorjones/code/oss/nokogiri/ports/i686-w64-mingw32/libxml
2/2.9.3"
      libxslt_path: "/home/flavorjones/code/oss/nokogiri/ports/i686-w64-mingw32/libxsl
t/1.1.28"
      libxml2_patches: []
      libxslt_patches:
      - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
      - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
      - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
      - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
      - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
      - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
      - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
      - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
      - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
      - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
      - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
      - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch
      - 0016-Fix-for-type-confusion-in-preprocessing-attributes.patch
      - 0017-Updated-config.guess.patch
      compiled: 2.9.3
      loaded: 2.9.3
```

So it's apparent that `nokogiri` is installed, because it took me about three hours to install it. Is there a work around so that I can include this version of `nokogiri`? I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This is for Windows 7 users running Ruby version: `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]` or higher attempting to install the `mechanize gem`***

---

If you are having issues installing `nokogiri` and `mechanize` here's how you do it successfully.

> Install `nokogiri`'s previous version first: `gem install nokogiri --pre`

Your output will look something like this:

```
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Nokogiri is built with the packaged libraries: libxml2-2.9.3, libxslt-1.1.28, zlib-1.2
.8, libiconv-1.14.
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.8.rc3-x86-mingw32
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 12 seconds
1 gem installed
```

> After you have it successfully installed, install `nokogiri` version 1.6: `gem install nokogiri -v 1.6`

The output will look like this:

```
Fetching: mini_portile-0.5.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.5.3
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for mini_portile-0.5.3
Installing ri documentation for mini_portile-0.5.3
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32
Done installing documentation for mini_portile, nokogiri after 9 seconds
2 gems installed
```

> And finally go ahead and install `mechanize`, IT WILL WORK! `gem install mechanize`

Finally you will have `mechanize` installed!

```
Fetching: mechanize-2.7.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mechanize-2.7.4
Parsing documentation for mechanize-2.7.4
Installing ri documentation for mechanize-2.7.4
Done installing documentation for mechanize after 9 seconds
1 gem installed
```

*Notes*:

- You may be able to bypass the first part, `gem install nokogiri --pre` it wouldn't allow me to continue until a version of `nokogiri` was installed already, but I'm not sure if that was just my system or not.
- This is the only workaround that I have discovered in order to install `mechanize` and `nokogiri`, if you encounter a problem please let me know, so I can find a further solution for the problem.